# How to continue a wp php script after function / continue html

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function fire_header() {
 if ( is_front_page() ) :
  get_header( 'me' );
 else :
  get_header( 'me' );
  fire();
 endif;
}
if ( is_plugin_active( 'fire/fire.php' ) ) :
 echo fire_header();
else :
;
endif;
?>
```

It is part of a wordpress page.php file. I need the function to run 2 parts if one specific plugin is active and 1 part if the plugin is NOT active AND also continue as normal to process the whole page file and finish at normal footer ending.

Comment: You want code to run after _after_ [`exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) has been called?

Comment: Yes I think that is correct... Code to run (php) / & display (html). For example here are the next few lines.
 <div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main">
   <?php
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

Comment: `exit` terminates the script, plain and simple. If you want more code to run, don't use `exit`.

Comment: No other function continues. I've tried others, continue, return, etc. I'm not a programer.

Comment: I also try writing only a semicolon

Comment: See the code now. I removed exit, and it still does not function as wanted. Thoughts?

Comment: It is still not really clear what you are trying to do. The function `fire_header` doesn't `return` anything, so `echo fire_header();` doesn't make sense, you only need to do `fire_header();`. Also, using the alternative `:` syntax for `if` statements isn't wrong, but it is very strange to see it at the same time as curly brace `{}` syntax is used. Do you have PHP and WordPress error reporting turned on?

Comment: Your commends gave me many ideas and I tried 3 or 4 different ways and it still does not do what I want. So let me explain. It is the wordpress page.php file. I need the function to run 2 parts if one specific plugin is active and 1 part if the plugin is NOT active AND also continue as normal to process the whole page file and finish at normal footer ending.